# Timeout ao executar o APK em emulador

Tags: android, android-eclipse, emulador

Estou com problemas ao rodar emulador no *Eclipse ADT*. Ao executar o *APK*, só dá **timeout**, mesmo aumentando o tempo do *ADB* para 50000 por exemplo. O projeto executa direto no celular, somente no emulador que não (já tentei até no *Genymotion*, sem sucesso). Alguém sabe uma solução?

Após o **timeout**, ocorre isso:

> New package not yet registered with the system. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.

Depois:

> [2015-05-16 22:39:06 - ddmlib] Uma conexão estabelecida foi anulada pelo software no computador host

O manifest está assim:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.com.nota.ui" android:versionCode="2" android:versionName="1.1">

    <uses-sdk 
        android:minSdkVersion="15" 
        android:targetSdkVersion="22"/>

    <application 
        android:icon="@drawable/notes" 
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <activity 
            android:name="br.com.nota.ui.MainActivity" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity android:name="br.com.nota.ui.NotaUI" android:label="@string/app_name"/>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Considere incluir o log da inicialização do emulador, talvez ele contenha algo que nos ajude a propor uma solução.

Comment: Aparece o seguinte no Logcat: Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'

Comment: Compilar e instalar o apk manualmente funciona normalmente?